# Can't access a mongoose response object property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I try to access an response obj from mongoose, it doesn't not return anything. Following is my code

```
//app.ts
import { User } from './Models/User';
router.get('/reset/:token', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: '60a12460479e874db836d939' }).lean()
   
    console.log(user)//returns an object with email property
    console.log(user.email) //returns undefined
    return res.json({
        user,
    })
})
```

Whereas this works fine

```
//app.ts
import { User } from '../Models/User';

router.get('/reset/:token', async (req, res) => {
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: '60a12460479e874db836d939' }, (err: any, user: any) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            console.log(user.email)//returns email
        })
        return res.json({
            user,
        })
    })
```

I have tried researching about this problem. Most of them seem to point out schema. But my schema seems to be fine.

Following is my schema

```
//Models/User.ts

    import mongoose from 'mongoose'
    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        isAdmin: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        resetPasswordToken: String,
        resetPasswordExpires: Date
    })
    
    export const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it without `lean()` method?

Comment: Doesnt't work as well , user returns an obj but user.email returns undefined